# Android couldnot parse http response where as iphone can

Tags: java, android, http, servlets

In android and iPhone are using same webservices, iPhone can parse response successfully where as android fails.

logs in android says

```
07-23 17:14:10.121: I/com.android.cashww.terminal.webservice.Webservice(2668): Code:200
07-23 17:14:10.175: I/com.android.cashww.terminal.webservice.Webservice(2668): �_�������?D&M�¶�g���K'��>K�<��
07-23 17:14:10.175: I/com.android.cashww.terminal.webservice.Webservice(2668): �R���CJ���~m�e�c���������Z�%�h;�<F+�������������a�@���GF7R��ۣ�N��Bq�����S��%�=����I,�,Ϲj%mra;��:����+�_��+bO��H4ܣ�>�\�����EC��O-vY\X�F|!�pM�6tò�&��x�M3��i7b�ϷG,�eb!�J������D��`7��D�;[ʯ�.&
07-23 17:14:10.175: I/com.android.cashww.terminal.webservice.Webservice(2668): ����wy�X�7�G|���<9#l<a{d�$j�ۢ!Qn�ǴCׅ[w5�,�x�"�7�qϧ�{d�]3B6f�z�un�����,ŴM-�
```

But expected an xml response

Android code:

```
String cset = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(entity);
ret = EntityUtils.toString(entity,cset);
```

One thing too : I enabled mod_deflate filter in apache

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

 SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary

 Make proxies work as they should.
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header append Vary User-Agent
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whereas your current problem can't be solved without the full code, I highly recommend you use  https://github.com/octo-online/robospice, not only will it handle everything for you, it adds caching and other features